# Query for two different result sets and then filter on a column that each contain

Tags: sql, oracle, simplification

I had a large explanation (in my mind it was an explanation, in reality it was more 10 pages of rambling) and then my browser crashed. So, I'll just give a quick overview of the problem as I'm not sure exactly what information is needed.

I have the following query model. The one on top is what currently happens and the one below is what I need to happen

```
                DetailsTable
                      |            
                 ObjectTable1
                      |            
              OtherDetailsTable

                DetailsTable
               /            \
         ObjectTable1  ObjectTable2
               \            /
              OtherDetailsTable
```

ObjectTable1 and ObjectTable2 store different objects and are both children of one parent object that contains no data.

They have foreign keys which link them to the other tables.

The query I need is generated by code and seems to like using uniontables (I can't really control this unless I hardcode the query which isn't really an option.

The current Query generated is the following:

```
SELECT UNIONTABLE.objectID, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID, 
       UNIONTABLE.f, 
       UNIONTABLE.updatedate, 
       UNIONTABLE.version, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.amount, 
       UNIONTABLE.currency, 
       UNIONTABLE.name, 
       UNIONTABLE.number, 
       UNIONTABLE.funds, 
       UNIONTABLE.print, 
       UNIONTABLE.paydate, 
       UNIONTABLE.recover, 
       UNIONTABLE.address, 
       UNIONTABLE.payee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymentspay, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymentspay 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT DT.objectID, 
                    DT.UniqueID, 
                    DT.f, 
                    DT.updatedate, 
                    DT.version, 
                    DT.objectID_updatedby, 
                    DT.unqiueID_updatedby, 
                    DT.amount, 
                    DT.currency, 
                    DT.name, 
                    DT.number, 
                    DT.funds, 
                    DT.print, 
                    DT.paydate, 
                    DT.recover, 
                    DT.address, 
                    DT.payee, 
                    DT.objectID_nominated, 
                    DT.uniqueID_nominated, 
                    DT.objectID_override, 
                    DT.uniqueID_override, 
                    DT.objectID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.objectID_paymentspay, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymentspay 
    FROM   DetailsTable DT, 
           ObjectTable1 OT1, 
           OtherDetailsTable ODT 
    WHERE  DT.uniqueID = OT1.uniqueID_ForeignKey1 
           AND OT1.uniqueID_ForeignKey2 = ODT.uniqueiD 
           AND Upper(ODT.Name) = 'STOCK1' 
           ) UNIONTABLE 
ORDER  BY UNIONTABLE.objectID, 
          UNIONTABLE.uniqueID
```

This would work correctly if there was only one ObjectTable. In order to get the correct results for the required model, I have the query

```
SELECT UNIONTABLE.objectID, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID, 
       UNIONTABLE.f, 
       UNIONTABLE.updatedate, 
       UNIONTABLE.version, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.amount, 
       UNIONTABLE.currency, 
       UNIONTABLE.name, 
       UNIONTABLE.number, 
       UNIONTABLE.funds, 
       UNIONTABLE.print, 
       UNIONTABLE.paydate, 
       UNIONTABLE.recover, 
       UNIONTABLE.address, 
       UNIONTABLE.payee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymentspay, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymentspay 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT DT.objectID, 
                    DT.UniqueID, 
                    DT.f, 
                    DT.updatedate, 
                    DT.version, 
                    DT.objectID_updatedby, 
                    DT.unqiueID_updatedby, 
                    DT.amount, 
                    DT.currency, 
                    DT.name, 
                    DT.number, 
                    DT.funds, 
                    DT.print, 
                    DT.paydate, 
                    DT.recover, 
                    DT.address, 
                    DT.payee, 
                    DT.objectID_nominated, 
                    DT.uniqueID_nominated, 
                    DT.objectID_override, 
                    DT.uniqueID_override, 
                    DT.objectID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.objectID_paymentspay, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymentspay 
    FROM   DetailsTable DT, 
           ObjectTable1 OT1, 
           OtherDetailsTable ODT 
    WHERE  DT.uniqueID = OT1.uniqueID_ForeignKey1 
           AND OT1.uniqueID_ForeignKey2 = ODT.uniqueiD 
           AND Upper(ODT.Name) = 'STOCK1' 
           ) UNIONTABLE 
    UNION
SELECT UNIONTABLE.objectID, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID, 
       UNIONTABLE.f, 
       UNIONTABLE.updatedate, 
       UNIONTABLE.version, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_updatedby, 
       UNIONTABLE.amount, 
       UNIONTABLE.currency, 
       UNIONTABLE.name, 
       UNIONTABLE.number, 
       UNIONTABLE.funds, 
       UNIONTABLE.print, 
       UNIONTABLE.paydate, 
       UNIONTABLE.recover, 
       UNIONTABLE.address, 
       UNIONTABLE.payee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_nominated, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_override, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymntspayee, 
       UNIONTABLE.objectID_paymentspay, 
       UNIONTABLE.unqiueID_paymentspay 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT DT.objectID, 
                    DT.UniqueID, 
                    DT.f, 
                    DT.updatedate, 
                    DT.version, 
                    DT.objectID_updatedby, 
                    DT.unqiueID_updatedby, 
                    DT.amount, 
                    DT.currency, 
                    DT.name, 
                    DT.number, 
                    DT.funds, 
                    DT.print, 
                    DT.paydate, 
                    DT.recover, 
                    DT.address, 
                    DT.payee, 
                    DT.objectID_nominated, 
                    DT.uniqueID_nominated, 
                    DT.objectID_override, 
                    DT.uniqueID_override, 
                    DT.objectID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymntspayee, 
                    DT.objectID_paymentspay, 
                    DT.uniqueID_paymentspay 
    FROM   DetailsTable DT, 
           ObjectTable1 OT2, 
           OtherDetailsTable ODT 
    WHERE  DT.uniqueID = OT2.uniqueID_ForeignKey1 
           AND OT2.uniqueID_ForeignKey2 = ODT.uniqueiD 
           AND Upper(ODT.Name) = 'STOCK1' 
           ) UNIONTABLE 
    Order by objectID, uniqueID
```

This will get the right number of results, however, I really need to simplify this as doing this through the current code generators will be... tricky.

Also, I had to change the orderby from

```
ORDER  BY UNIONTABLE.objectID, 
          UNIONTABLE.uniqueID
```

To

```
Order by objectID, uniqueID
```

because it was giving out.

So yea, is there an easier way to do this? Its using Oracle

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an easier way to do this?

Well, you can replace `ObjectTable1 OT1` with

```
(SELECT * FROM ObjectTable1 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM ObjectTable2) OT1
```

It *is* "easier", but I don't know how much performance are you losing.

Comment: Eugh, seems I was mistaken about them having exact same columns. Seems one has a couple of extensions I missed :/. Gonna update original post. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I could actually just select the columns i need from both instead of select *. That could solve my issues...